# LINQ search by text

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to do a linq, 
"When the txtKeyword.Text is empty, the query will return all data, or else it will return the data that contains the txtKeyword.Text."

```
        var search = from a in Context.data
                     where txtKeyword.Text.Trim().Count() > 0 ? a.Name.Contains(txtKeyword.Text.Trim()) : true
                     select a;
```

---

```
Error:
DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.
Parameter name: input
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you give of a non-linq example of what values should be selected under what scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var search =     from a in Context.data
                 where string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtKeyword.Text) 
                 || a.Name.Contains(txtKeyword.Text.Trim())
                 select a;
```

Comment: Fede's answer below is much better.

Comment: Why so? While it really just seems like a style preference, I see no need to use 3 lines of code to do what can be accomplished in 1 clean/easy-to-read line.

Comment: The short answers is because (current) LINQ providers are stupid and won't optimize away the conditional before passing it on to the SQL Server.  This causes a number of performance problems because the query plan will be cached based on one of the conditions, but used for both.  So if you first query where Text is empty, it caches a plan on how to execute it (likely a table scan), and then if you supply Text, it still uses the same exact query plan (ignoring any indexes it could have used to determine if Name Contained the text).

Comment: Ah, thanks. This will actually be quite useful knowledge for me going forward!

Comment: Not to mention the additional over head of having to build up a more complex expression tree, translate the more complex expression tree to SQL, then send the more complex (longer) SQL to the SQL server, then have SQL server parse and optimize it, etc etc.  It's best just to remove the complexity right there in the C# before it goes any further.  Granted, in most cases, the performance difference here is minimal (this portion of it, assuming they ever fix the query plan caching issue), it is completely avoidable, so why not?

Comment: This link goes into much better detail:http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/ Just realize that your LINQ statement gets turned into a parameterized query that has the same characteristics as a stored procedure.  By including (or not including) the where clause, you will essentially be creating two separate stored procedures, each with their own separate query plan getting cached. Should that link disappear, a quick google for "SQL parameter sniffing" should turn up additional information as well.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the query expression is too complex for the query builder.

I would separate that code like this:

```
var search = Context.data;
string filter = txtKeyword.Text.Trim();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
    search = search.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(filter));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var search = from a in Context.data
             where txtKeyword.Text.Trim().Any() 
                   || a.Name.Contains(txtKeyword.Text)
             select a;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the conditional check on txtKeyword out of the linq statement.
Something like this

```
var search = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtKeyword.Text)
            ? (from a in Context.data
                where a.Name.Contains(txtKeyword.Text.Trim())
                select a)
            : (from a in Context.data select a);
```

Comment: I think other approaches are better because you don't duplicate any query.

Comment: I see what you mean.  With more complex queries I can see that becoming an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var searchText = txtKeyword.Text.Trim();
var returnAll = string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText);

var search = from a in Context.data
                 where returnAll || a.Name.Contains(searchText)
                 select a;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.